# org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value while using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting this error while inserting data into table using Spring boot framework via POSTMAN RESTAPI:

> `org.hibernate.PropertyValueException`: not-null property references a null or transient value: `com.example.demo.model.Employee.firstName`

This is my Employee Entity class:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")

public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you set constructor with lomboak?

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor?
```

Check other column constrain like `nullable =false`

Answer (score 0):

Find a way to initialize the String firstName attribute. You actually enforced a not null contrail but may not have sent the value before attempting to persist.

So, when u create the object for the Employee class, make sure u set a value for the first name before u save it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

remove the @Column and it will work